# Compare database value from laravel to a javascript value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, laravel

I have a simple seating chart that has a designated ip address. It is generated through  javascript. And I have a database that is occasionally being populated by ip address and computer name. I query the database using Laravel.

Routes.php

```
Route::get('seatplan', 'SeatplanController@seatplan');
```

Controller

```
public function seatplan()
{

$ipadd = Client::all();
return View::make('seatplan',['ipadd' => $ipadd]);

}
```

Blade

```
@foreach($ipadd as $ipadds)
    {{$ipadds->ipadd}}
    <br />
@endforeach
```

How can I compare them so that if  a new data is inserted in the database I can compare the ip address and display the computer name. 
Here is my js

```
var cols = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
var seatNum = 1;
var n = "192.168.240.";

for (var i = cols.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
  for (var j = 0; j < cols[i].children.length; j++) {
    cols[i].children[j].innerHTML = n.concat(seatNum);
    seatNum++;
  }
} else {
  for (var j = cols[i].children.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    cols[i].children[j].innerHTML = n.concat(seatNum);
    seatNum++;
   }
  }

}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZNzoV

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQB6R.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but what I understand you are trying to do is to determine which seats are taken, correct?

If so, juste generate a JS variable from you PHP data. Instead of doing a `foreach`, do: `<script>var takenSeats = <?php json_encode($ipadd) ?></script>`.I don't know Laraval so I use plain PHP but the point is to use `json_encode` so that your PHP array will be rendered as a JS array and assigned to a global JS var.

Then update your JS to have (for example):

```
var text = n.concat(seatNum);
if (takenSeats.indexOf(ip) !== -1) {
  ip += ' taken';
}
cols[i].children[j].innerHTML = text;
```

As this code necessits the `takenSeats` variable to be initialised make sure to put the `json_encode` **before** this.

Here is [a fork of your codepen illustrating this](http://codepen.io/chadrien/pen/zqGoBx)

Comment: You are right sir! Do I just leave the var takenSeats = [] empty once I get the variable in PHP?

Comment: If you're talking about the code in codepen, you should remove. As codepen is HTML/CSS/JS only (no PHP) I had to initialise the variable by this mean. But once you generate the variable with PHP, remove this. `takenSeats = []` you empty your array and you wouldn't want that :)

Comment: Ah I see.. So the values are just stored in  _var takenSeats = <?php json_encode($ipadd) ?>_  ?

Comment: Yes, that's why it's important to have this first, otherwise in your JS code, it will be `undefined`

Comment: Cool! I'll just find a way about the laravel part. thanks sir :D

Comment: may i ask what is the use of indexOf(ip)?

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf` can be used to know if an element is part of an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/indexOf